# Converting list of strings into ints splits them up by the digit

Tags: python

Right now I'm using:

```
intListUptime = [list(map(int, each)) for each in listUptime]
```

The problem is this splits up the numbers into their digits, so `'992'` would become `[9, 9, 2]`.

How can I convert them so I get `992`.

The end goal is to sort the list but first I have to convert them into its because they range from one digit to four digits and sorting them as strings does stuff like put 2000 behind 900.

Comment: I think you just need `[int(each) for each in listUptime]`.

Comment: Can we have an example of the content of listUptime?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us a complete code snippet that we can copy-and-paste into our editors, run, and then see the problem. As it is now, we do not see the problem. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).